How can I improve my dose-response curves?
I am very new to dose-response modelling, so I am currently using scripts that I found in a paper and I'm struggling to make the dose response curve look acceptable using drc and ggplot2 in Rstudio. I would like to get rid of the gaps between the data and the axes and I'm also not sure why the x axis values are bunched down the end and not at regular intervals.
structure(list(nickel = c(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 50, 50, 75, 75, 
                          113, 113, 169, 169, 253, 253, 380, 380, 570, 570, 854, 854, 1281, 
                          1281, 1922, 1922, 2883, 2883, 4325, 4325), growth = c(100L, 104L, 
                          101L, 93L, 101L, 100L, 94L, 75L, 74L, 71L, 60L, 85L, 72L, 52L, 
                          53L, 71L, 65L, 43L, 55L, 49L, 38L, 40L, 50L, 35L, 20L, 0L, 0L, 
                          17L)), row.names = c(NA, -28L), class = "data.frame")

Ni.m1 <- drm(dose_response.data$growth~dose_response.data$nickel, data = dose_response.data, fct = LL.3())

newdata <- expand.grid(conc=exp(seq(log(0.1), log(6000), length=200)))
pm <- predict(Ni.m1, newdata=newdata, interval="prediction")

newdata$p <- pm[,1]
newdata$pmin <- pm[,2]
newdata$pmax <- pm[,3]

dose_response.data$nickel <- dose_response.data$nickel
dose_response.data$nickel[dose_response.data$nickel == 0] <- 0.5

ggplot(dose_response.data, aes(x = nickel, y = growth))+
  geom_point(pch=1,cex=2) +
  geom_ribbon(data=newdata, aes(x=conc, y=p, ymin=pmin, ymax=pmax), alpha=0.2) +
  geom_line(data=newdata, aes(x=conc, y=p)) +
  coord_trans(x="log") +
  xlab("Nickel"~(µg.L^{-1})) + 
  ylab("Growth (% control)") +
  ylim (-20,130) +
#manually add lines representing the EC10 concentration
  geom_segment(aes(x = 42.5, y = 0, xend = 42.5, yend = 90), linetype = 2, lwd=1) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = 0.1, y = 90, xend = 42.5, yend = 90), linetype = 2, lwd=1) 

Result:


The values are bunched because you asked for a log(arithmic) scale - coord_trans(x="log")

And your vertical reference line does not extend to the x axis because your geom_ribbon has values for ymin that are below zero but you specify y = 0 in your first geom_segment.
